# How do I add Sentry reporting to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Hello I am creating a React app and want to use Sentry error reporting. The documents they provide seem to be a bit unclear or outdated, because I don't have a raven.js file in the npm package they provide. Instead everything is coming from sentry/browser.

Comment: Hey Noah, not really sure what your question is but have you looked at the React section of the Sentry docs? https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/react/

Comment: Yes I have checked it out. I'm unclear on it